# Sublime Text 3 - Error loading syntax file "Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax"

Tags: python, sublimetext3

After creating a new build system and saving it, every subsequent time I start Sublime Text 3 I get an error message that says:

Error loading syntax file "Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax": Unable to read Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax

Answer (score 9):

I found that if I click on the OK button on the alert dialog box and then close all the open tabs in Sublime Text 3 and then close ST3 and reopen it, the error message no longer comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close all the tabs and re-open the ST3 to resolve this.

This error is due to your `Session.sublime_session` file is holding an invalid reference to "Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax". You can open the `Session.sublime_session` file and by removing that reference, this issue can be resolved. In my case error was due to the "Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax" instead of "Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax".

1. Open ST3 and go to Preferences -> Browse Packages... from the toolbar.
2. This should open a new explorer window on the path `C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`.
3. Close ST3
4. Go one directory back and open `Local` folder. Now you should be in the path `C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local` where the `Session.sublime_session` is located.
5. Open the `Session.sublime_session` with an editor other than ST3.
6. Find the text "Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax" and delete the line and save the file.
7. In my case it was "Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax" giving the error as per the below screenshot.
8. Restart ST3 and the problem should be resolved now.

[image: Line of the invalid reference]